# How can we measure the relative speed to a star that is many light years away?

Tags: special-relativity

This is a relativity question: how it is possible that we can measure, using Doppler effect, the relative speed to a star that is many light years away, establishing relative velocity with a source that could not know who will see its emissions?

Comment: What do you mean by many light years away? If it is near enough to use special relativity (as indicated by tags), then there is simply no question. You just use Doppler as usual and there is no issue. Further than that, relative speed makes little sense. You must talk instead of the expansion of the universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no time dilation in relativistic Doppler as is easily seen considering a star away, it could not know who the observer is and thus also not know the relative speed to the future observer. Once this is understood, we realize that Doppler effect is created entirely in the process of actual light observation. In Einstein 1905 paper he proposes that the light front phase is an invariant (he speaks in language of his time, invariants were not yet invented), he says that omega t - \vec k. vec x, the light wave phase, has the same value for all inertial observers. Choosing two different observers, one comoving with source, and one e.g. on Earth one finds applying to coordinates t, x the Lorentz transformation, how omega and \vec k change between the two observers to keep the phase invariant - and Einstein states the well known Doppler shift and aberration formulas we use today in his paper.  Unfortunately Max von Laue writing about Einstein results compares transverse Doppler to time dilation and this is translated incorrectly into English to mean that Doppler has origin in time dilation, and propagated by Resnik in his many books (Resnik did not to best of my knowledge had ever taken a class in relativity but writes books about this topic). This misconception propagates on and is now found on Wikipedia page guarded by Resnik disciples who perpetuate and propagate false relativity. Fundamental lesson here is to be on guard not always to trust Wikipedia, and, moreover, look for education papers written by research scientists, such exist, see for example http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S160057751700769X (open access) addressing another aspect of this misunderstanding.  We learn: Doppler effect (shift, aberration) is created by observer interpretation of the invariant light wave phase.  2nd lesson: do not trust Wikipedia or Physics books if the contents makes no good sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are several routes that can be taken in answering this question. I will take one and invite others to try different ones.

The light given off by any object travels through space without any regard of the location of someone or some thing that later detects it, because the detector is in the beam's *future*. For that to be false would require some aspect of light to travel faster than the light beam, reach the detector first, and then travel back to affect in some way the rest of the light beam before it arrives at the detector. Since faster than light travel is impossible, that scenario cannot occur, and the object sending the beam of light towards us is in our *past* at the moment the beam is sent and is causally disconnected from the object detecting it *in the present*.

Another way to see this is as follows:

The light from a distant object has been traveling towards us for some period of time- from fractions of a second to billions of years, depending on its distance from us. When that beam of light reaches us, it informs us of the state of the emitting object at the instant the light left it, from a fraction of a second ago to billions of years ago. We are seeing that object's *history*, not its *present*, when we are looking at that beam of light. Since we cannot rewrite or alter the past, the object that sent the beam towards us cannot be affected by our receipt of that beam.

Comment: You do see the problem - for solution please see the answer I just posted.